# I don't get notification (and I cannot follow) for post on a site’s Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Whenever I post on the wall of a site I like, I don't get any notifications when someone likes my post (does not matter) or comments under my post (matters). Also, when I'm viewing the post, Facebook does not automatically update post activity using AJAX, like it does on walls of my friends (matters as hell). So I must press F5 like I was on some forum. Can this be solved? And if yes, how?

Comment: @Alex your edit wasn't really valid. I'm asking specifically about facebook page/site posts, not posts on my or friend's wall. Edits shouldn't alter post meaning.

Comment: I got it, but instead of rolling back, you should’ve just add the missing “site” in the title.

Comment: @Alex It already was there when I first posted this question. Also, *And if yes, how?* is such an obvious question I can't see a reason to add it. Are your edits always that intrusive? Maybe you should take a look on edit guidelines.